# Identifying the literary technique

Tags: literary-techniques, rhetoric

I was wondering if there is a literary technique in the following quote:

> "Let us be sacrificers but not butchers"

Comment: Hello Jaydon, I think your question might fit more the [Writers SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Only one I can think of is metaphor, if the phrase here wasn't meant literally. But Alenanno's right, this is wrong forum

Comment: @Philoto, Alenanno if he 1) rephrase 'literary technique' into speech pattern or 'language usage technique' (or my favorite - 'rhetorical technique'), 2) asks for a *word* that describes it - would you then see the question as appropriate for EL&U?

Comment: @Unreason You can always call the black white, but that won't make it actually white, will it? We use metaphor and hyperbole in common speech quite often, but that doesn't make them "language using techniques". They are still literary techniques.

Comment: @Philoto, and you can also claim that gray does not exist because you only have white and black paint; I am sincerely trying for objectivity here. Rhetoric is "the study of effective *speaking* and *writing*." - it studies the *use of language* (name of this site) in *general* (not only literary). It could certainly apply here.

Comment: @Unreason Hey, who said gray exists? It's simply a white with lots of dust on it! Seriously, rhetoric in my opinion is not exactly a language usage, it is a different (and language independent) art of presenting your argument - exactly what we are doing at this very moment. This site is dedicated specifically to patterns in the English language, thus rhetoric is also outside it's scope. It's just my feeling, you're free to agree or disagree, but I really doubt it will change.

Comment: @Unreason And [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30208/rhetorical-device-in-julius-caesar) we've got your follower :) I seem to be outnumbered, but my determination won't wither!

Comment: @Philoto, good argument regarding rhetoric not specific to a particular language (at least not as much as grammar is), but I would still argue that it falls under usage. For example, if someone asks is certain expression *sarcastic* I think there is no objection that this is appropriate for EL&U. For me, that is also a question that should be tagged [tag:rhetoric]. Anyway, this is noisy for here, so... http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/does-rhetoric-fall-under-elu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under classic rhetoric I think this would be called [correctio](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/C/correctio.htm) (L. “correction, amendment”)

> **correctio**
>   The amending of a term or phrase just employed; or, a futher specifying of meaning, especially by indicating what something is not (which may occur either before or after the term or phrase used). A kind of redefinition, often employed as a parenthesis (an interruption) or as a climax.

example:

> *I desire not your love, but your submissive obedience.*

It might also be called [restrictio](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/R/restrictio.htm) (from L. restringere “to restrain”)

> **restrictio**
>   Making an exception to a previously made statement. Restricting or limiting what has already been said.

example:

> *She's the most beautiful woman in the world—present company excepted.*