# Rhetorical device in Julius Caesar

Tags: rhetoric

I thrice presented him a kingly crown/ which he did thrice refuse"

Just wondering what the rhetorical technique is in that phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Although Ham and Bacon suggests anastrophe, this could also be an [example of diacope](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/diacopeterm.htm).

> The repetition of a word or phrase
>   broken up by one or more intervening
>   words. Plural diacopae or diacopes:
>   "Put out the light, and then put out
>   the light." (Othello, the Moor of
>   Venice V.ii)

Comment: +1, http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/D/diacope.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think this is poetical. There's the repetition of the word "thrice" for emphasis on the number of times it was done.

IT's also a little bit of anastrophe, that is, the words were arranged a little strangely i.e. which he did thrice refuse, so that the words would rhyme properly, or so that the rhythmn will be better.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a bit, I think I have a more specific term than Raven

[**Epanalepsis**](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/E/epanalepsis.htm) from Gk. *ep*, "in addition", *ana*, "again," and *lepsis*, "a taking". It is also known as **resumptio, the echo sound, the slow return, resumption**.

> Repetition of the same word or clause after intervening matter. More strictly, *repetition at the end of a line, phrase, or clause of the word or words that occurred at the beginning* of the same line, phrase, or clause.

examples:

- *"In times like these, it is helpful to remember that there have always been times like these."* —Paul Harvey
- *"Believe not all you can hear, tell not all you believe."* —Native American proverb
- *"A lie begets a lie."* —English proverb
- *"To each the boulders that have fallen to each."*
  —Robert Frost, "Mending Wall"

It falls under [figures of repetition](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/of%20Repetition.htm) for which *conduplicatio* and *ploce* are general terms. [Diacope](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/D/diacope.htm) is a very close relative and I think it applies here as well. However, diacope, from etymology - "to cut in two, cut through" with common name *the doubler* suggest that more emphasis is on duplication and emotion:

> from Shakespeare's Tempest:
>   *"All lost! To prayers, to prayers! All lost!"*

where epanalepsis describes the exact structure..